# Odd pages should be right

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided

I'm writing a document using `srcbook`. It has quite many pages and I have the following scenario:

The first ~10 pages are numbered with small roman numbers (i.e. i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii, ...). These pages contain preface, table of contents, and such stuff.

After these pages, I continue with ordinary arabic page numbers. The problem however is the following: The first page with arabic numbers is *on the left*. This results in the face that all `\part`s and `\chapter`s start on the left page.

However, I would like to start them on the right page.

So, I tried the option `openright` to enforce new chapters opening on the right page. However, LaTeX seems to check this property according to the page number.

Of course, I can simply insert an empty page to enforce this manually, but this seems like a hack.

Is there any way to acchieve what I want more elegant?

Comment: then there is something wrong with your setting, because `openright` is the default for a `twoside` document.

Comment: Perhaps a minimal example would help? I thought what you wanted was the default behaviour. Are you using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`?

Comment: @Herbert Thank you. You were right, I didn't use proper settings.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the hint - it solved the problem. If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\cleardoublepage` or `\frontmatter`/ `\mainmatter`to separate the parts. `\newpage` alone will confuse latex.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
 first page
\mainmatter%
%\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering {arabic}

\chapter{blub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` solved the problem.